# Convert 1d numpy ndarray into one hot encoding ndarray of shape (n,2)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, encoding, numpy-ndarray

I have a 1d numpy ndarray with shape `(1,2)`.

```
nd = array[1,0]
```

I want to convert it into a ndarray with shape `(n,2)` such that it will look something like this;

```
nd_new = [
            [1,0]
            [1,0]
            [1,0]
            ...
            ...
            [1,0]
         ]
```

There are `n` rows of `[1,0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) as follows:

```
>>> np.tile(nd, (n, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question. Use the one hot encoding tools from keras.

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
y_nd_ones = [1] * n
y_nd = to_categorical(y_nd_ones)
```